# Add reply URL to Azure Active Directory register app via command line

Tags: powershell, azure-devops, azure-active-directory, azure-pipelines, azure-cli

### I have an Azure Active Directory app and it has various reply URLs. I've being adding reply URLs manually in the Azure portal AAD-> register-app-> settings-> reply-URLS.

My goal is to be able to run an azure pipeline task that can retrieve the reply URL I need from an azure app service( which I know how to do) and add it to the reply URL list from the register app in AAD with a command. Using either Azure-cli, Azure-powershell or Powershell from azure pipeline task list.

If there's another way of doing it with another task I'm open to suggestions.

### This is what i tried:

[image]

### This is what the log/debug output:

I guess that a better questions is:

### How Can I give privileges to an Azure CLI task from Azure DevOps to achieve the task from previous problem?

[image]

Comment: For now it hasn't given me the Privileges error. but is giving me this one: Get-AzureADApplication : **You must call the Connect-AzureAD cmdlet before calling any other cmdlets.** This is the page I ended up and will try this command and let everubody knwo if it worked. In another note thanks @Rohit-Saigal your answer helped me pass a rode block I had since last Thursday.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your question has changed a bit after your edit, so I've tried to revise and answer both parts.. i.e. adding reply URLs through script and something to possibly help with privileges issues:

**Adding Reply URLs to your application through PowerShell script**

Make use of application object's ReplyUrls list and [Set-AzureADApplication](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azuread/set-azureadapplication?view=azureadps-2.0) command. Here's a quick sample script:

```
# ObjectId for application from App Registrations in your AzureAD
$appObjectId = "<Your Application Object Id>"

$app = Get-AzureADApplication -ObjectId $appObjectId

# reply URL to add
$newURL = "https://mynewurl"

# Existing reply URLs list
$replyURLList = $app.ReplyUrls;

$replyURLList.Add($newURL)

Set-AzureADApplication -ObjectId $app.ObjectId -ReplyUrls $replyURLList
```

**Assigning correct privileges for execution of script**

To execute your script as part of pipeline, this article provides very detailed step-by-step instructions: [Set up continuous deployment in Azure Pipelines](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/vs-azure-tools-resource-groups-ci-in-vsts#set-up-continuous-deployment-in-azure-pipelines)

I would point you to option 1 in the article, which talks about creating a separate application/service principal for executing the script. Once you do that, you can assign the required privileges to this service principal that will be used to execute the script and resolve your current issue of insufficient privileges.

Screenshot for important parts from article:
[image]
[image]

For step h, you can follow the first link to register application from Azure Portal.

Once you have the separate application/service principal created for executing script, please go to it's settings > Required Permissions

[image]

"Windows Azure Active Directory" should already be available in list of APIs (if not, you can click Add button to add it)

Pick the appropriate privilege under application permissions.

[image]

Make sure you go through Admin consent at the end of this process by clicking on the "Grant permissions" button at the end of this process.

[image]

Comment: the link  "Set up continuous deployment in Azure Pipelines" does not work. either way I'll proceed with your solution and see how it goes. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @BAcevedo You're welcome. I have edited to correct the link.

Comment: The problem I'm having is that the Docs are out of date with the new Azure DevOps interface and some of the options mention in the steps do not appear. Also the docs assumes that my powershell script is in a repo but is not. This process I'm trying in deployment not build. Any suggestions apart from the current one? thanks in advance.